# Get particular row data from jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I want to get a particular row data from jQuery data table. Can anyone help me to get the record with first column id?

```
function showchnldetail(val) {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(val);
    if (null != aData) {
        alert('enter');
    }               
}
```

`val` is first column id. I want to store the data in a variable.

```
var aDataSet = [ ['96', 'xx', 'product1', '144']];
```

I assign the above dataset to `otable`.

Comment: I really need more information. Could you post a snippet of your #example table?

Comment: Example table data like this  var aDataSet = [
    ['96', 'xx', 'product1', '144']];

Comment: Did you check the documentation? http://www.datatables.net/api, fnGetData accept the index of the tr or the index of the column of the dataset.

Comment: please show more code. I suspect you already created `oTable`. Also need to see what `val` is that you are passing to function

Comment: charlieftl Please see my post again

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodes = datatable.fnGetNodes();
var row = null;

jQuery.each(nodes, function(key, fila){
    if(jQuery(fila).attr('id') == idrow){
        row = fila;
    }
});       

var pos = datatable.fnGetPosition(row);
      datatable.fnUpdate('new value', pos, 1);
```